# What is the best way to check an event occurred in the past in SVA?

Tags: system-verilog, assertion, system-verilog-assertions

I want to check in my design that when signal b get asserted, then signal a should have gotten asserted 3 to 5 cycles before.

I'm looking for the different ways to check that.

Currently I'm using the following logic

```
sequence s_test();
##1 $rose(a) ##[3:5] 1;
endsequence

property p_test();
##1 $rose(b) |-> s_test.triggered();
```

Is there a way to check that property without using the sequence triggered mechanism ? I guess I could also use something like $past(a, 3) || ... || $past(a, 5), but that's cumbersome.

Also what's the difference between the sequence triggered and matched mechanism ?

Comment: `.triggered` is exactly how I'd do it.

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between triggered and ended ?

Comment: No. But `.ended` is deprecated in IEEE 1800-2009, `.triggered` should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

We can have two approaches here: **cause then effect** or **effect because of cause**.

**Cause then effect approach**:

You can use a *forward-time-based assertion* stating that when `s_test` is triggered, then `b` should go high in 1-5 clock period of time window:

```
s_test.triggered |-> ##[1:5] $rose(b);
```

**Effect then cause approach**:

Alternatively, if `s_test` is a *signal*, then you can use a glue logic which monitors past 5 values of `s_test`. Thereafter, the assertion checks that the earlier values of `s_test` must have atleast 1'b1 when `b` rises from 0 to 1.

```
bit[1:5] earlier; 
always  @(posedge clk) begin
  earlier <= {s_test, earlier[1:5]}; // shift for 5 clocks
end

p1_past20: assert property(@(posedge clk)
 $rose(b) |-> $countones(earlier) >= 1);
```

A similar discussion is available [here](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/sva-using-past) and a reference is over [here](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/sva-check-event-occurred-window-time-past).

Comment: Generally, assertions are written as a chain reaction of cause then effect, rather than effect because of cause? I think you need to check both: you need to not only check that the cause causes the effect, but also that the effect was caused by the cause (ie was not spurious). So, for example, I not only should check that a request results in a grant, but also I should check that any grant was caused by a preceding request.

Comment: Totally agree!! The statement is more of an easier approach to the OP's question. I have updated the write-up. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$past` something like below.

```
property test_past;
  @(posedge clk)
    $rose(b) |-> ##[3:5] $past(a);
endproperty
```

Answer (score 1):

`triggered` & `matched` methods differ for single clock & multi clock sequences.

Both methods show end point of a sequence, but `triggered` method evaluates to true if the operand sequence has reached it's end point at that particular time and false otherwise.

Whereas `matched` method detects endpoint of sequence, referenced in multiclocked sequence. So it provides synchronization between 2 sequences and evaluates to true after match, untill arrival of 1st clock tick of destination sequence.

`triggered` status of a sequence is set in observed region and is persisted through the remainder of the timestep. Whereas `matched` status of a sequence is set in observed region and is persisted untill the observed region of the arrival of first clock tick of destination sequence after match.